# Deploying JavaFX Project as jar

Tags: java, javafx, deployment, terminal

so I am right now trying to deploy a javaFX Project of mine.
I am using the [Gradle shadowJar Plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow).

I got the jar all File and everything and am now trying to execute it via Terminal.

The Project itself runs in IntelliJ without a problem. I also had it running like half a year already but lost the information on how to run it after a pc-crash (unluckily). So I know that it works just dont know how.

However I have to include this VM Option:

```
--add-exports javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event=org.controlsfx.controls
```

Right now my command is the following:

```
java --module-path .\jdk-18.0.2\lib\ --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar .\kantine-all.jar
```

going off from the Directory:

```
C:\Users\(ME)\Desktop\DEPLOYMENT
```

The Error I am getting is:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found
```

If I run it without add module or module path it says JFX Runtime component missing.

Comment: Generally, expecting to be able to run a JavaFX application from a jar file is probably not the direction to go. Look at the "Packaging" section in the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info) for alternative options. Your current attempt is failing because the runtime can't find the modules you are trying to add: JavaFX modules are not included in `JDK-x.x.x/lib`. You need to download the JavaFX mods and specify the path (or find the correct path if they are already on your computer) to them for this approach to work. (The result will not be very portable.)

Comment: Alright Thanks a lot.. I do know that deploying a jfx project as a executable jar is not really the usual way to go but in this case i have no other choice. But I will try that.

Comment: Specifically, if Gradle is your build tool of choice, then look at [`badass-jlink`](https://badass-jlink-plugin.beryx.org/releases/latest/) for modular apps (or [`badass-runtime`](https://badass-runtime-plugin.beryx.org/releases/latest/) for non-modular apps). Those are the defacto standard for packaging JavaFX applications using Gradle. Documentation is at the badass site and also in openjfx.io getting started documents.

Comment: Examples for badass-runtime [usage](https://github.com/beryx-gist/badass-runtime-example-javafx) and [build.gradle](https://github.com/beryx-gist/badass-runtime-example-javafx/blob/master/build.gradle).  Similarly, for badass-jlink [usage](https://github.com/beryx-gist/badass-jlink-example-log4j2-javafx) and [build.gradle](https://github.com/beryx-gist/badass-jlink-example-log4j2-javafx/blob/master/build.gradle).

Comment: If you must use shade, then [an example using Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653836/maven-shade-javafx-runtime-components-are-missing), similarly [for Gradle](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/), section in openjfx getting started documents: Runtime images | Non-modular project | Gradle.

Comment: If you are creating a fat executable JAR file and JavaFX itself is being included in that JAR file, then your main class **cannot** be a subclass of `javafx.application.Application`. You **must** create a separate "launcher class" and set it as your main class. At minimum, all the main method of this "launcher class" needs to do is launch the JavaFX application. I also recommend that you configure the `shadowJar` task (from _Gradle Shadow Plugin_) to exclude all `module-info.class` files. And make sure the native code of JavaFX is included in the fat JAR.

Comment: If that doesn't help, then please [edit] your question to add a [mre].

Comment: Alright. I am right now sticking to badass-jlink, like jewelsea said. But however i cannot use it anyways cause I have a different problem not allowing me to go on with working on this problem. Once I have figured out the other one I can go on with this problem here. Thanks a lot tho.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this full configured, running and executable non modular JavaFX application:

https://github.com/davidweber411/javafx-JavaFxAppGradleNonModular

There is a Gradle task "createCustomFatJar" which will generate an executable JAR file.

PS: You can download this project and build in top of it too!